# Creating multiple buttons using a variable

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I'm trying to build a for function to create multiple buttons with random cases.

What I don't know is how to use my variables to create those buttons??

Here is the part of my code:

position string is to determinate which button i'm creating.
showButton string is to determinate which button id i'm using.

```
string showButton, position;                
for(int i = 1; i<=12; i++)
        {

            showButton = "imagebutton" + i;
            position = "position" + i;


        Random random = new Random();
        int randomNum = random.Next(1,4);

        switch (randomNum)
        {
            case 1:

                ImageButton position = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.showButton);
                position1.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.buttonGreen);
                btnPosition.Click += (o, e) =>
                    {
                        Toast.MakeText(this, "Você venceu", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                    };
                break;
            case 2:
                SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
                ImageButton position = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.showButton);
                position.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.buttonYellow);
                position.Click += (o, e) =>
                    {
                        Toast.MakeText(this, "Você Venceu", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                    };
                break;
            case 3:
                SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
                ImageButton position = FindViewById<ImageButton>(Resource.Id.showButton);
                position.SetImageResource(Resource.Drawable.buttonRed);
                position.Click += (o, e) =>
                    {
                        Toast.MakeText(this, "Você Perdeu", ToastLength.Short).Show();
                    };
                break;
        }
```

Comment: what is the problem with your code?

Comment: The problem is: My program is not recognizing position and showButton as variables, so instead of reading its value, is reading the name of the variable. Like he can't create a "position" imagebutton because this variable its already taken, but of course, i wanted to make him read the variable position and use as position1...position12

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of problems with the code. First you declare two variables of the type `string` namely `showButton` and `position`. The latter is then declared again in the inner scope of the switch. So when you get out of that scope and reference `position` you will get the `string` variable and not the button, I am not sure if that is intended.

Next I think you are trying to use the `showButton` variable to as a combination of `Resource.Id.` and `showButton`, this will not work! `Resource.Id.<someId>` are all defined in the `Resource.Designer.cs` file, which is generated on each build, from the Ids defined in you axml files. Referencing variables from a string name is not possible like that. What you could do is to have a method which from the `showButton` variable returns the correct Id for the button.

Also it seems that you have already added all the buttons to your `Main.axml` file and what I think you want to do is to inflate new buttons and then add them when needed to the `Main.axml` file, positioned according to your `position` variable.
So here you should create a new axml file, with your button definition. Inflate it in your code and then add it to the view.

Comment: Yes, I already added all the buttons I need in my Main.axml file. What I want to do is to build 3 different cases for each one of them. I could do it one by one(and believe me, I already did), but what I'm trying to make is all of them with a loop so I can add all other functions in a simpler way, instead of making the same code 100 times more and making it more complicated...